# Problems with CreateView eyesight, django bug?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

**( I come from stackoverflow in Spanish for help )**

I have an interesting problem, first of all the model as such:

```
class Reserve(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    employee_of_turn = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

The problem is to create an instance of the `Reserve` model through the `CreateView` view, which will create a form to create that instance, but in the form I do not want to display the field `employee_of_turn` I want only the client field to be shown and that by default the value of the field `employee_of_turn` is the user who logged in at that time.

Well to solve this problem, try to modify the data sent by the POST method, in the `get_form_kwargs` method:

```
class ReserveCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Reserve
    template_name = 'testapp1/example.html'
    fields = ['client']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        if form_kwargs.get('data'):
            user = User.objects.get(username = self.request.user)
            post = self.request.POST.copy()
            post['employee_of_turn'] = str(user.pk)
            form_kwargs['data'] = post

        return form_kwargs
```

The fact is that it does not work, I always get this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: testapp1_reserve.employee_of_turn_id
```

I started trying to figure out where exactly the error occurred, because the solution of the `get_form_kwargs` method that I showed earlier, should fix the error, and the error occurs in the `form_valid` method, specifically in the `form.save()`, here the source code of the method `form_valid`:

> **ModelFormMixin:**
>
> ```
>  def form_valid(self, form):
>      """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
>      self.object = form.save()
>      return super().form_valid(form)
> ```
>
> **FormMixin:**
>
> ```
> def form_valid(self, form):
>     """If the form is valid, redirect to the supplied URL."""
>     return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
> ```

---

**( I did the following with the intention of seeing how the structure of the data is when the instance was created, without omitting fields and when the field `employee_of_turn` was omitted, in order to replicate the structure at the time of omitting said field and at the time of modify said data, and thus be able to solve the problem, avoiding errors )**

### Case 1:

In the `form_valid` method, I printed `form.data` when in the fields attribute it had the following value:

```
fields = ['client']
```

### Case 2:

Then I did the same but in this case the fields attribute had the following values:

```
fields = ['client', 'employee_of_turn']
```

---

I printed the data in the `form_valid` method in the following way, since this was where the error specifically arose and there was a possibility that the data was not sent as I modified it before:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    print(form.data)
```

The result of printing it in the 2 cases was as follows:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['SBRSJa0aw4iNJOMPwtQVsFL6V6y1cFMNGne9Kr0fA7YmtYeD8xshhDq6pc1mKjQs'], 'client': ['code2'], 'employee_of_turn': ['1']}>
```

That means that whether you print `form.data` in **Case 1** or **Case 2**, the data is exactly the same, which means that the problem is not the data at the time of modifying it, it is something else (I deduce).

Since even when printing `form.is_valid()` in the `form_valid` method, it results in `True`.

So why is it wrong, if I am replicating the data structure correctly when modifying it? I don't make sense of this error, the whole modification process I am doing correctly.

---

**Note:**

Many think that in reality the field `employee_of_turn` awaits an object in the form or view, I sent an id and may think that this is the error, but it is not so.

First of all, I tried, instead of putting an id in the field `employee_of_turn`, I put an object, and gave the same error.

The reason that the field `employee_of_turn` expects an id and not an object is because this is how the view manages it, at least when receiving the data by the POST method, I don't know why it is managed like this, that's how they decided Django developers.

This can be verified in **Case 2**, no fields are omitted, the two fields are filled in normally and the data entered in the `form_valid` method is printed as follows: `form.data`.

Printing it results in:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['SBRSJa0aw4iNJOMPwtQVsFL6V6y1cFMNGne9Kr0fA7YmtYeD8xshhDq6pc1mKjQs'], 'client': ['code2'], 'employee_of_turn': ['1']}>
```

Clearly it can be seen that the key `employee_of_turn` has an `id` value, not an object.

There it can be verified that the field `employee_of_turn` does not expect an object as such, at least not at that stage of the view.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you're getting the error you are is because you don't have the `employee_of_turn` field in your `fields` attribute. That means that even when you are adding it to the POST data the value *is not* being passed into the model.

Behind the scenes the `CreateView` is creating a `ModelForm` from a factory function, which is ultimately what is creating the instance of `Reserve`. Without including the `employee_of_turn` field the form doesn't know about it and can't handle it even though the model is expecting it.

While you're correct in saying that the instance of `Reserve` is created in the `form_valid` method (defined at https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.3/django/views/generic/edit.py#L123), it is created *by* `form.save()` with `form` being an instance of a `ModelForm` (defined at https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.3/django/forms/models.py#L443). This means that the `ModelForm` is in fact holding the logic of creating the `Reserve` instance.

What I think you really should do is override the `get_initial` method of your view and provide the user there. Make sure that you include `'employee_of_turn'` in your `fields` attribute.

```py
    def get_initial(self):
        return {'employee_of_turn': self.request.user}
```

If I understand you correctly, you want to have the `employee_of_turn` field hidden for HTML. In that case you'll need to create a `ModelForm` for the `Reserve` model. When you do you should add this code to the `Meta`.

```py
    class Meta:
        widgets = {'employee_of_turn': forms.HiddenInput}
```

There are a couple of other features that I immediately see which might be useful, but both of which necessitate a `ModelForm` subclass. These are extra that I would probably put in.

**Login required mixin**

You might already be doing this and just not considered it relevant to your problem. I would suggest adding `django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin` to your view. Any time that I use the `request.user` attribute and expect the user to be authenticated I would add this mixin to make sure.

**Preserved initial data**

I'm guessing that you don't want the input tampered with and even hiding the field doesn't prevent the input being changed by bots or people who know about "inspect element".

Django's built-in user change form implements this kind of protection on it's password field (https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.3/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L149). You might be interested in something similar to enforce that the value in the field is not changed.

Comment: I just did what he told me but I still get the same error. I want to do it this way not with a `ModelForm`, more than anything I want to know why the error.

Comment: This should work without a `ModelForm`. You should be able to just implement the `get_initial` method that I outlined to provide the user to your field and make sure your `fields` attribute is set to `fields = ['client', 'employee_of_turn']`.

Comment: If I implemented the get_initial method and it didn't work, I didn't put in `fields` ` employee_of_turn '`, because the `employee_of_turn` field is going to appear on the form and I don't want that.

Comment: Then you need to either implement a `ModelForm` or go further into the code than I understand. You can't do anything with `'employee_of_turn'` unless the form also knows to expect it.

Comment: ok, but I still don't understand why the error, you know why exactly the error happens?

Comment: Did you see the edit I made to the answer? I added a couple of paragraphs to the beginning doing my best to explain.

Comment: Ok, I read it. But because when I add the POST data, why don't the values ​​be passed to the model?

Comment: It should be noted that the `form_valid` method is the one that is responsible for creating the intact model, and the data reach that method completely and correctly, so why the error?

Comment: The fact that the data arrives complete and correct to the form_valid method is because I modified it correctly in the get_form_kwargs method, so I ask why the error?